# How to correctly configure retries for uploads to Azure Blob Storage in Go

Tags: azure, go, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to perform retries in case an upload fails to azure blob storage. Does the sdk offer such a mechanism? I was able to find this stuct `azblob.RetryReaderOptions` but as I understand it can only be used while downloading files.

Do I just have to have to just run the upload through a loop and breakaway in case of success?

This is the code I have right now.

`azup.uploadResult, azup.err = azblob.UploadFileToBlockBlob(ctx, f, *azup.blockBlobURL, azblob.UploadToBlockBlobOptions{})`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to perform retries in case an upload fails to azure blob
> storage. Does the sdk offer such a mechanism?

The blob storage API doc about go is here:

https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob

You can find sdk didn't offer such a mechanism.

> Do I just have to run the upload through a loop and
> breakaway in case of success?

I think this idea is fine. SDK does not provide an upload retry mechanism, so you have to implement it through code.